# the latest logon session is retained and the user is automatically signed out from the other session

Tags: asp.net, session, authentication

Let suppose, I am building an asp.net website which has login scenario in it. I want to provide a certain functionality to the website that if the user is already login on computer 1 and now try to login on computer 2, so he will be allowed to remain login on computer 2, while automatically logout him from computer 1.

I also know that http is a stateless medium, so whenever user interact with computer 1 and try to interact with the page, it will get noticed at that time.

Comment: Do you talk to a database on every page interaction? And are you using InProc, StateServer, SQL or custom session state? (The two questions aren't related, I'm just thinking of vague ideas at the moment)

Comment: Well, yes I am talking with the database on every page almost. Still, its not decided where we're maintaining our session, but most probably in InProc mechanism.

Answer (score 1):

You need to store the additional data (the computer currently 'logged in') in the database, or application state.  Then when you process the authentication request - check to see if the machine you stored matches the one requesting authentication - if it does not, you would force the user to log-in and store the new computer (ip address) in the database/application state.

Comment: We can't use the computer (IP Address), because at corporate level, they are using the proxy server and it will ruin our solution.

Comment: You could use sessionId instead, keyed by UserLogin.  When you authenticate, check if the sessionId matches the latest one stored, if so let them through, if not redirect to login page.  You could also do this with a GUID added to a session cookie which Furqan touches on below.

Answer (score 1):

In case Tony's suggestion does not fulfill your purpose, You need to generate a hash comprising of "UserLoginName" + "HOST_NAME" +"TIME" (or any combination you like) and store that hash in your Database against that loginName and also send that hash to the user in a Cookie. 
On subsequent request you can check through a handler or module if that specific cookie is submitted and contains the value matching your database, if it matches then the user is coming from the same machine and no need to update anything , if not user is coming from some other machine either the cookie shall not be there or would be containing some other hash value so you should send him to Login page again and upon login just recreate the hash and update it in your database against his login.
Hope this shall work.